# Slash before text in CSS

Tags: html, css

I trying do somethink like this:

[image: ---]

```
.line {
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

a:hover .line {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.text {
   position: relative;
    top: -7px;
}

<a href="#">
<span class="line">/</span>
 <span class="text">Home Page</span>
</a>
```

But when I try scale this line, it's move all links.
I want to scale this line from center and without move all elements.

```css
a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.line {
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: all .3s linear;
}

a:hover .line {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.text {
   position: relative;
    top: -7px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
<span class="line">/</span>
 <span class="text">Home Page</span>
</a>  
<br>
<a href="#">
<span class="line">/</span>
 <span class="text">Another Page</span>
</a>  
<br>
<a href="#">
<span class="line">/</span>
 <span class="text">Another Page 2</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Give the span a fixed width so that it doesn't change in width when you scale the slash...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't adjust the font-size, use a `scale` transform instead.

```css
a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.line {
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  display: inline-block;
  /* required */
}
a:hover .line {
  transform: scale(0.75);
}
.text {
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span class="line">/</span>
  <span class="text">Home Page</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="#">
  <span class="line">/</span>
  <span class="text">Another Page</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="#">
  <span class="line">/</span>
  <span class="text">Another Page 2</span>
</a>
```

Even better...don't use an extra span *just for styling*, use a pseudo-element instead...but the same principal applies.

```css
a,
a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:before {
  content: '/';
  font-size: 40px;
  transition: all .3s linear;
  display: inline-block;
}
a:hover:before {
  transform: scale(0.75);
}
.text {
  position: relative;
  top: -7px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <span class="text">Home Page</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="#">
  <span class="text">Another Page</span>
</a>
<br>
<a href="#">
  <span class="text">Another Page 2</span>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks! I'll remember this ;) I'll accept this answer in (7 minutes) :)

Comment: To make it larger use `1.5` in scale `a:hover .line {-ms-transform: scale(1.5); /* IE 9 */  -webkit-transform: scale(1.5); /* Safari */  transform: scale(1.5);}`